# How to set the width of window editor tabs to evenly distribute?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The question says it all. I'd like to have the width of the tabs in the editor to be of the same width. Like how it is in Google Chrome for example.

[image: Current tab bar]

Answer (score 0):

Extension [Custom CSS and JS](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css).

Your `custom.css`

```css
.tabs-container > .tab {
    flex-grow: 1; /*evenly distribute space*/
    min-width: 12% !important; /*width of the entire tab*/
    max-width: 12% !important;
}
.tabs-container > .tab > .tab-label {
     max-width: 90%; /*fix shifting close icon*/
}
.tabs-container > .tab > .tab-label > .label-name {
    display: inline-block; /*necessary for overflow work*/
    max-width: 87%; /*text width*/
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Sweet extension. But I'm not sure if it's activated. Is there an easy way to see if the custom.css is loaded?

Comment: .monaco-editor-background {
    background-color: red !important;
}

Comment: Thank you! I found out that you need an extra `/` if you reference a local file 
 `file:///Users/<name>/vscode/custom.css`